# Use an Ecto query to find what leagues belong to a particular user

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have `User` and `League` they relate to each other by has_many through `users_leagues`. Pretty basic setup.

But now I'm trying to query on leagues that have an association with a particular user. So, if `User A` has a relationship with `league A` but not with `League B` I want to just see `League A` when I query leagues.

This is one of those cases that it seems Rails is such an easier approach. In rails this would be: `@leagues = current_user.leagues`
`
Here is my current attempt:

```
    def my_leagues(conn, _params) do
      current_user_id = Coherence.current_user(conn).id
      query = from l in League,
      select: l

      leagues = query |> where([l], l.users == ^current_user_id) |> Repo.preload(:users)|> Repo.all 

      render(conn, "my_leagues.html", leagues: leagues)
    end
```

## ERROR:

```
no match of right hand side value: #Ecto.Query<from l in Statcasters.League, where: l.users == ^1, select: l>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including the stack trace and the line where the error originates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ecto.Query.join/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5) accepts associations as `join` values:

```
query = from l in League,
        left_join: u in assoc(l, :users),
        where: u.id == ^current_user_id.
        select: l
```